# How can I use DateTime to get the time to this format?

Tags: python, date, datetime

```
'Wed, 18 Sep 2013 22:22:44 -0700'
```

I tried `datetime.datetime.now().strftime`, but I can't get it perfectly in that format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want:

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```

More info [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

To get the result you want you would use:

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```

for the -0700 (timezone offset) part to print anything other than a blank string you need to pass in a timezone aware date (for example US/Arizona in -0700 UTC). To do this (using a third party `pytz` module, you would do the following) :

```
import pytz
datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone("US/Arizona")).strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```